# What is the difference between crypto.createHash and crypto.createHmac?

Tags: node.js, encryption, openssl

The [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createhash_algorithm_options) describe the technical difference, but not the practical difference.

Comment: What do you mean that you don't see any practical differences? A hash expects one input (data) and an HMAC two (key and data). I would say those are very important practical differences. They also have very different use cases.

Comment: @ArtjomB. could you describe the use cases in an answer?

Comment: No, because not their use cases, but their properties are important. If you understand their properties then you can assess if they make sense for your use case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The documentation already assumes you understand what is used for what purpose.

A cryptographic **hash** is a one-way function creating a fixed-length output from the input of any length. You can image the *hash* function as a "fingerprint". Theoretically it is not possible to create a unique hash for any input, but the crypto hash functions are designed that the collision probability is negligible and it is not possible to compute the original input.  (there are some other features, but these are basic functional requirements)

Typical use cases are

- integrity check, if the input was not changed accidentally
- short identification of large data
- anonymization of data

[HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) is similar as a *hash*, but HMAC requires a key as an additional input.

Common use cases:

- the same as *hash*
- integrity check to ensure, that the input was not changed (even intentionally).
- undeniability - make sure the data was produced by the key owner